# For loop execution in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a oracle scheduler performing an operation which has a for loop inside, based on some condition i am holding the operation for sometime, but once the condition gets met for not holding, its not getting to the next element in for

```
    for c in (select plan_name from test1 where plan_name like('plan_1','plan_2')
    <<checkStatus>>
    begin
    select progress,status into progress_value,status_value from (select progress,status from dtw_run_log where plan_name=c.plan_name  order by raised_timestamp desc) where rownum=1;
    while(status_value!='Failed' or (progress_value !=100 and status_value!='Complete'))
    loop
    goto checkStatus; 
    end loop;
    end; 
    end loop;
```

Comment: This is not Java. tagging it incorrectly will not give you a better chance at getting an answer

Comment: This code will not run at all. The like operator does not accept a list of literals. The outer for-loop misses the 'loop' keyword. And the select-statement that retrieves the status should go into the while-loop, so you don't need the label and the goto-statement anymore.

Comment: It will also fail with no-data-found if there is no record in the log for the plan. And you're recursively opening loops via the goto (very fast - should you be sleeping between checks?) so I think Oracle will either kill it or eventually keel over. There are better ways to detect status changes. In this case a trigger might be enough, but it depends what the outer loop is really going to be, and what you plan to do once your conditions are matched.